# Is there a way to get the length of an object field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following objects in `MongoDB`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "pencil",
        "purchase_record": {
            "1":"$900",
            "2":"$1000",
            "3":"$1100",
            "4":"$1200"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "pen",
        "purchase_record": {
            "1":"$1000",
            "2":"$1200",
            "3":"$900",
            "4":"$1100",
            "5":"$1100"
        }
    }
]
```

Is there a way to get the length of `purchase_record` for each record?

Comment: Not without using map/reduce. Have you considered making `purchase_record` an array?

Comment: Can you check my answer? An updated, and simpler answer to this old question =)

Comment: Sorry, it is an old question and I have quit using MongoDB already. Too many problem caused by this NoSQL database.

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question, but the answer is very easy with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/), that is available from MongoDB version 3.4.4

You can just do;

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      purchaseCount: {
        $size: {
          "$objectToArray": "$purchase_record"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Which will give out the count of fields within `purchase_record`, and the result will be;

```
[
  {
    "name": "pencil",
    "purchaseCount": 4
  },
  {
    "name": "pen",
    "purchaseCount": 5
  }
]
```

See it interactively on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jQbQ-CdUXF8)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider to change your documents structure making `purchase_record` an array as @JohnnyHK pointed out. The best way to do this is by using ["bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations.

```js
var bulk = db.xx.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;
db.xx.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    var purchase_record = doc.purchase_record; 
    var newRecord = []; 
    for(var key in purchase_record) {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(purchase_record, key))
            newRecord.push({'units': key, 'price': purchase_record[key]});
    } 
    bulk.find( { '_id': doc._id } ).updateOne( {
        '$set': { 'purchase_record': newRecord } } ); 
    count++; 
    if(count % 300 === 0) { 
        // Execute per 300 operations
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.xx.initializeUnorderedBulkOp(); 
    } 
})

// Clean up queues
if (count > 0) bulk.execute();
```

After this operation your documents look like this:

```js
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565aad654036f6520c25a9bb"),
        "name" : "pencil",
        "purchase_record" : [
                {
                        "units" : "1",
                        "price" : "$900"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "2",
                        "price" : "$1000"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "3",
                        "price" : "$1100"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "4",
                        "price" : "$1200"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("565aad654036f6520c25a9bc"),
        "name" : "pen",
        "purchase_record" : [
                {
                        "units" : "1",
                        "price" : "$1000"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "2",
                        "price" : "$1200"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "3",
                        "price" : "$900"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "4",
                        "price" : "$1100"
                },
                {
                        "units" : "5",
                        "price" : "$1100"
                }
        ]
}
```

---

You can now use the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) your documents and return the "purchase_record" [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#exp._S_size)

```js
db.xx.aggregate([
    { '$project': { 
        '_id': 0, 
        'name': 1, 
        'size_purchase_record': { '$size': '$purchase_record' } 
    }} 
])
```

Which returns:

```js
{ "name" : "pencil", "size_purchase_record" : 4 }
{ "name" : "pen", "size_purchase_record" : 5 }
```

You can always add the 'purchase_record' field to the result using:      `'purchase_record': 1`

---

With your document current structure you can use the the [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce) method to do this:

```js
var map = function() { 
    var records = []; 
    for(var key in this.purchase_record) {
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.purchase_record, key)) 
            records.push(key); 
    } 
    var recordsLen = records.length; 
    emit(this.name, recordsLen);
};
var reduce = function(key, values) { return values; };
db.xx.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: { inline: 1 } } );
```

Which returns:

```js
{
        "results" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "pen",
                        "value" : 5
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "pencil",
                        "value" : 4
                }
        ],
        "timeMillis" : 1,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 2,
                "reduce" : 0,
                "output" : 2
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Or the [`.map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.map/#cursor.map) method which is not efficient because it's client-side.

```js
db.xx.find().map(function(doc) { 
    return {
        'name': doc.name, 
        'purchase_record_len': Object.keys(doc.purchase_record).length
    }; 
})
```

Which yields:

```js
[
        {
                "name" : "pencil",
                "purchase_record_len" : 4
        },
        {
                "name" : "pen",
                "purchase_record_len" : 5
        }
]
```